# Is there a command line tool for validating RDF files?

Tags: command-line, software-rec, xml

I am looking for a substitution of the [W3C RDF Validator](http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/), as it is broken, in addition I want something a bit more automated, such as a command line tool.

I have been using `xmllint` for checking XML files in the past. Are there any command line tools similar to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **rapper** tool for validation or http://jena.sourceforge.net/Eyeball/

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Jena Eyeball](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/archive/eyeball/eyeball-manual.html) is no more maintained.

> [...] there is no Apache release of Eyeball and the code has not been updated for Jena3.

You can use [Apache Jena Riot](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tools/#command-line-tools-quick-reference) instead. Such as:

```
riot --validate dataset.rdf
```

Note that [rapper](https://librdf.org/raptor/) is a useful tool and is still maintained but it doesn't really do validation. For examples invalid XSD `dateTime`s are not detected.